# Images not loading in gmail for some regions like UAE & Europe

Tags: proxy, gmail

We are facing image broken issue in some regions like the UAE, France. Images are loading fine in application while accessing the image in browser. But after send that in mail we facing broken image issue.

Image url - https://example.com/zohocampaigns/59877000026671012_zc_v3_1665482240468_bigin_a_pipeline_centric_crm_built_for_small_businesses.jpg

Image url with Google proxy

```
           - https://ci6.googleusercontent.com/proxy/IRl_BC-ELTqzG1LLmVY9hTeXMXRE45u9jDZFkBPiHUy-IEr2vT_GwW6MAyJ1_F5_kgHDjfnsYTwiNOZaBa-kSbQ6iv7ca56C1qWHNOtxjUB6-JyE-SeQ1V00ljcNY_pAyGHRdKytl5RSl2VMp_0RuSRlWP3ilQofq4n6tFQXhhTyCViJKGN4EyFbOZFEZamNK-Akmqk8Cx57eRQ4IUg=s0-d-e1-ft#https://example.com/zohocampaigns/59877000026671012_zc_v3_1665482240468_bigin_a_pipeline_centric_crm_built_for_small_businesses.jpg
```

While working fine regions:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cFvUw.jpg)

While accessing from Europe region:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nH6B3.png)
Note - Here I hided my domain for security purpose.

Can anyone help to resolve this issue.